# NEST is much slower than Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

We have been testing Elastic Search for our logging system. There is 300 thousand data on an index in ElasticSearch cluster.

I have installed both Kibana and NEST on my PC. The cluster on a local server.

When I make a query from Kibana using Dev Tools, the response time is 1 or 2 ms and it brings 10 records

```
GET /dbmessages/_search
{
  "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    { "match": { "user": "Robin*" } }

  ]
}
  }
}
```

However with .NET client (using NEST), the response time is around 600 ms, even with the same query.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();    

var result = client.Search<Message>((s => s
        .Index("dbmessages")
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Query(q => q.Raw(@"  ""query"": { ""bool"": { ""must"": [ { ""match"": { ""user"": ""Robin*"" } } ] } }"))));

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

It is also slower if I use linq-like query.

```
 var response = client.Search<Message>(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Index("dbmessages")
.Type(typeof(Message))
.Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("Robin*"))));
```

Even mongoDb and SQLServer make select query faster (in ~25 ms). I believe something is wrong with NEST.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Sending the request directly to ES through Kibana or Sense will always be faster than sending the same query through any client language. The reason for this is that any client language will always add some execution overhead by itself. That overhead in turn depends on many factors related to the host on which you're executing your program/application (CPU, RAM, code quality, etc).

Comment: @Val Thank you for your response. So you're saying that there is nothing wrong with those numbers?

Comment: Without any further in depth rigorous performance testing, I don't think so. If you're just starting, I wouldn't worry too much about it, first craft your mappings in an optimal way according to the queries you'll need to run and the results you expect. When that's done, you can worry about performance, which will depend on your production host anyway.

Comment: @Val Thanks! I'll try to do so.

Comment: Bear in mind that the first query to Elasticsearch from NEST will be much slower because the client caches a lot of delegates, compiled expressions and json serialization properties on this first call. When running these kinds of benchmarks, it is advisable to run in release mode, prime caches first (make calls and discard results), send many calls, then take the percentiles of such calls. A tool such as BenchmarkDotNet can help here. Additionally, with the NEST call, you'll also be including serialization of search request and deserialization of result.

Comment: I've shared a more detailed answer on the discuss site: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nest-is-much-slower-than-kibana/66081/2